# Loading HTML list elements partially

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular4 app I have a list with few thousands of li elements.
li elements are showed when user clicks on ul element.
Expanding such amount of li's ofcourse is hard time to browser, sometimes it takse few seconds, other time the browser gets stuck.

I am looking for smart way how to load this elements partially.
I do not want to use paginantion.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of filteredData>
   <div></div> //and so on...
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use angular lazzyloading

Comment: use angular cdk infinite scrolling https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/infinite-virtual-scroll-angular-cdk/

Comment: I am looking for the simplest solution guys.

Comment: What do you mean by `simplest` solution? You can't do it by writing just 2 lines of code. What you need is a pagination without actual pages. You can use infinite scroll or "load more" button but both ways you need to pass a parameter to tell the server which items to load.

Comment: Lazy loading is your friend.

Comment: All data are fetched. I don't want to ask server for a piece of data (like in pagination approach). I'd like to show this data partially. Solution provided by Bear Ninthi looks great but maybe there is other more simple way to achive that.

Comment: @BearNithi suggested a solution without server-side loading. This is simple

Answer (score 0):

simply do load to some content

```
<div class="item active" *ngFor="#data of lengthArray;i=index">
    <div *ngIf="i<=4">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

or check this out [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uewdjk?file=app%2Fpeople-list%2Fpeople-list.component.html)

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of people">

      <!-- HERE: add a element with click event binding -->
      <a href="#" (click)="selectPerson(person)">
        {{person.name}} 
      </a>

  </li>
</ul>

<app-person-details [person]="selectedPerson"></app-person-details>
```